# Laplace Transform Csch(x) (1/Sinh(x))

Tags: special-functions, laplace-transform, hypergeometric-function

I need to find the Laplace Transform of $Csch(x)=\frac{1}{\sinh(x)}$. Wolfram Alpha and Mathematica [say](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace%20transform%20csch%28x%29) $-H(\frac{s-1}{2})$, where H(n) is the $n$-th Harmonic Number. I hope someone have a nice hint to proof this.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The integral for the Laplace transform for this function does not converge: for positive $s$, 
$$
\int_\delta^1\frac{2e^{-sx}}{e^x-e^{-x}}\,dx\geq e^{-s}\int_\delta^1\frac1{x}\,dx=e^{-s}\log\frac1\delta.
$$
So as $\delta\to0$, we see the integral diverge.

I'm assuming that Mathematica uses some relation with another transform, where the other transform does converge.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The integral diverge but the Laplace transform exists seems strange to me, how is this possible?

Comment: It depends on how the transform is defined. Sometimes, when you want to extend the domain of definition of a function, you look at equivalent formulations, and sometime these formulations work in a more general setting. If you look at the Wikipedia page on Laplace Transform, you'll see relations with several other transforms. My assumption is that Mathematica uses one of those relations to obtain a value for the LT, and so they can get an answer even though the original definition does not go through.